# magento disable a banner on certain category pages or have a banner with multiple links

Tags: magento, categories, banner

Is there a way to disable a banner on certain category pages, but not all of them? I am trying to have a banner on my category page that has 3 links to its sub categories. Since the banner can only be uploaded as a jpg and not html image I'm guessing it will need to be figured out with XML or maybe an extension???

Comment: If by banner you mean default Magento call-outs then you can use any HTML code you like within a call-out.

Comment: how would i go about handling this? sorry i am just starting out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <default>
   </default>
   <catalog_category_view>
     <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
   </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

**This will remove banner (dog photo banner) from category view page.
If you write under default tag like below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
       <default>
          <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
       </default>
    </layout>
```

**The banner would be removed from every page**

**P.S :- Write this code in local.xml
Path:-magento_folder/app/design/frontend/mytheme(your_package_folder)/neo(your_theme_folder)/layout/local.xml**